# Why add lupin flour to white bread?

Tags: bread, additives

We buy ordinary, American-style white sandwich bread from a national supermarket chain.  I just had a look at the ingredients and was surprised to see that, in addition to wheat flour, it contains [lupin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lupinus) flour (*Lupinenmehl* in German):

[image: Packaging for REWE Beste Wahl American Sandwich loaf, listing "Lupinenmehl" as one of the ingredients]

I know that lupin seeds are edible when prepared properly, but what are they doing in ordinary white bread?  I can't imagine that they're any cheaper than ordinary wheat flour.  And this isn't some sort of fancy artisanal bread where the use of exotic grains is a selling point; it's just the regular store-brand sandwich bread.  Does adding lupin flour in white wheat bread have a particular benefit in terms of taste, texture, preservation, etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a seller's product description[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.amazon.de/Lupinenmehl-aus-weissen-S%C3%BC%C3%9Flupine-500g/dp/B009E2GDV0):

> In der Backindustrie verwendet man Lupinenmehl als Zusatz zu Brotmischungen, da es das Brot aromatisiert, elastischer und länger haltbar macht.
>   (The baking industry uses lupin flour as additive in bread mixes because it makes the bread more aromatic, elastic and increases shelf life.)

Another description[<sup>2</sup>](https://www.ugb.de/lupinen-suesslupinen/suesslupinen-fleischersatz-aus-lupinen/):

> Das Mehl kann in Brot, Kleingebäck und Teigwaren verarbeitet werden. Lupinen-Mehl bindet relativ viel Wasser.
>   (The flour can be used in bread, pastry and pasta. Lupin flour binds comparatively much water.)

So it boils down to lupine flour being used as a dough enhancer, the content in your example being 1.5% or less of the *total bread weight* suggests that it probably is not really "tasteable", but influences either the manufacturing process or the texture of the bread. If lupine flour is used to alter the protein / carbs ratio, up to 15% of the *flour* is replaced by lupine.

So my *guess* is that the manufacturer benefits by being able to incorporate a tad more water (which is sold, too) and possibly a bit less gluten formation, making the dough easier to handle and giving it the "fluffiness" that a German customer expects from what is labeled as "American Sandwich" bread.

Comment: They make tofu out of lupin flour, so it must behave somewhat similar to a legume flour .. and such are commonly used as egg replacers, which would agree with the use as an elasticity enhancer...

Comment: Correct. Lupine is sold as "European soy", so to speak. In this answer I was focusing on explicit *baking* applications, not on "lupine meat" etc.

Comment: Lupins are edible?  Bah, that makes this old [Monty Python sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLkhx0eqK5w) slightly less funny.  (skip to 4:25 if you're in a hurry)

Comment: @Joe your standard garden variety lupin contains toxic alkaloids and need [special treatment](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/64765/preparing-lupini-beans) before they can be used as food. The lupins discussed in the question are a special breed with little to no alkaloids.